# Keep hyperlinks if cell text is vbred

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

i have some code that deletes the hyperlinks in a range. What i am trying to do  is keep the hyperlinks if the cells text is vbRed. The code below seems to delete all links in all the cells.

```
    Sub RemoveHyperlinks()


    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range


    Set rng = Range("CourseName")

   For Each cel In rng

    If cel <> vbRed Then

    cel.Hyperlinks.Delete

    With rng.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = vbBlack
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Did below answer help you or still you need help?

Comment: hi @Harun24HR, sorry for the late reply, popped out. Still need help as did not work.

Comment: Is the red color the result of a conditional formatting ? If yes use the same condition as for the conditional format, instead of testing the red color or use the following property  `cel.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color <> vbred

Comment: Hi yes,  I have just found out that is is because of conditional formatting. Will have a look. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to run following codes first to grab `ColorIndex` of a cell. This code will show you the `ColorIndex` in a message box.

```
Sub GetColorIndex()
    MsgBox "Cell Interior ColorIndex: " & Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex
    MsgBox "Cell Font ColorIndex: " & Range("A1").Font.ColorIndex
End Sub
```

After getting `ColorIndex`, use that value as parameter of `IF` condition. Suppose cell `A1` font color is red then messagebox will show you `ColorIndex=3`. Then use following codes to remove hyperlink.

```
Sub RemHyperlink()
    If Range("A1").Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        Range("A1").Hyperlinks.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

> ## Edited Answer

Check this line. `If cell.DisplayFormat.Font.ColorIndex <> 3 Then` Full sub will be as following.

```
Sub RemoveHyperlinks()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range("CourseName")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
    End If


    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.DisplayFormat.Font.ColorIndex <> 3 Then
         cell.ClearHyperlinks
         cell.Font.Underline = False
         End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, yes thanks. BUt it still deletes all the hyperlinks in all the cells. i am trying to keep the hyperlinks in cells that are equal to vbRed and deleter the others

Comment: It shouldn't do that. Can you please share a screenshot of your data? Also try to share a sample file via google drive or dropbox to have a look in your sheet.

Comment: Hi here the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10HvqX7XxZcDsBLmLFGdHg-FDtD1lyOQt) to the file. It is a quick sample file that works with conditional formatting. Links are already in place

Comment: @RobertHall I have checked your link. See my edited answer.

Comment: Hi, i have inserted the code and it is still doing the same. I think it might be the clearhyperlinks that is causing the problem as it wants to clear all the hyperlinks in the range. I have even removed a hyperlink manually and it removes the links from the range.

Comment: @RobertHall [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yyjHDkd-dhY2XXo5xbiTDlzrN-cKhyqX/view?usp=sharing) the solved file and check. It will remove hyperlinks from non red text cells. Let me know your feedback.

Comment: Perfect, i see my problem now. The links were to an external source and that was only for testing. You Sir, are a star.

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks if `cel` value is 255 (`vbRed` value). You need to narrow check down to an attribute of your `cel` variable like that:

```
If cel.Font.Color <> vbRed
```

Comment: hi, typed that in and still the same